# How to isolate (detour) internal constructor with Microsoft Fakes shim?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I found bunch of examples with StreamReader but how to detour internal constructor? I need to create fakes of some public class with internal constructor to be able to test my code isolated.

Imagine I have

```
public class ChangesPostProcessor
{
    public void Process(IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry> changes)
    {
    ...
    }
 }
```

In this particular case I need to fake set of DbEntityEntry to be able to mock his numerous methods (working with DB) and test my logic isolated.

Comment: You need to apply an interface to DbEntityEntry and inject it instead.  That will allow you to inject a mock of IDbEntityEntry.

Comment: DbEntityEntry is class from Entity Framework, I can't apply anything to it!

Comment: You can wrap it and apply the interface to the wrapper.

Comment: I don't even need Fakes for this. But I would really like to avoid it!

Comment: For things that are not interfaces or virtual, you need to use Shims rather than Fakes.

Comment: Dear Jack A., could you please explain how to use shim to detour internal constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally went with wrapper approach and implemented IDbEntityEnty interface with my own class with public constructor, containing DbEntityEntry inside.
It lets me test but made me to rewrite enormous amount of code to change dependencies from DbEntityEntry to IDbEntityEntry.